# How to apply function to field in values_list lookup

Tags: django, django-views, python-3.6, django-queryset

My line of code goes:

```
replies = Comment.objects.filter(reply_to__pk__exact=pk).annotate(dates=timesince.timesince('date'))\
        .order_by('-dates')\
        .values_list("owner__username", "text", "dates", "likes", "owner__customuser__picture")
```

I want the dates column in the result to be transformed by the `timesince.timesince` function. Instead, it throws an error like so:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'
```

How do I resolve this?

EDIT 1: Based on request by @GrandPhuba, the tracback after implementing the second solution is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/Bonychicken/main/views.py", line 374, in get_replies
    print(comments)
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 252, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1095, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 260, in convert_datetimefield_value
    value = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/lord-sarcastic/.local/share/virtualenvs/Bonychicken-xy3Z_xpD/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: This does not originate from this, you somewhere have written `.year`, where that object is a string, not a `datetime` object (or something similar).

Comment: Well, nothing like that is in my code. There is no place I called any attribute ot the ```dates``` column

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.expressions import Func
comments = Comment.objects.annotate(
    age=Func(F('date'), function='AGE') # other functions can be found here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html
).values_list('age')
```

Or for a more DB agnostic solution

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.expressions import Value
from django.utils import timezone
comments = Comment.objects.annotate(
    age=Value(timezone.now()) - F('date') # subtract the comment.date from timezone.now()
).values_list('age')
```

Comment: I used the second solution since I'm not working with Postgres and it raised an error: ```TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: Since I'm testing locally, I'm using default sqlite.

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Can you try `age=timezone.now()  - F('date')` (without the `Value(...)`)  instead

Comment: Same error. The error gets raised whenever I call a function that evaluates it, such as ```print```, ```len```

Comment: How about converting that timezone.now() to a string? `age=str(timezone.now) - F('date')`

Comment: Same error. I think the ```annotate``` method is where the issue lies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210624/discussion-between-grandphuba-and-lord-sarcastic).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kinda fixed my bug by changing my approach to solving the problem.

```
            {
                "username": comment.owner.username,
                "text": comment.text,
                "date": timesince.timesince(comment.date),
                "likes": comment.likes,
                "picture": comment.owner.customuser.picture.url
            } for comment in Comment.objects.filter(reply_to__pk__exact=pk)
        ]
```

While this only avoids the problem, it solves it!